# Convert text from image into text file

Tags: matlab, ocr

I have an image and I want to convert it text file to use in word processing software. 1) Can it be done in any software. 2) Is it possible to write a program in Matlab or any other language that can convert it to text. The font is really poor in the image file.[image: Text Image]

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about OCR where there are existing libraries that can be used for this. I suggest you take a look at Leadtools OCR. I used it in .NET environment and it can convert images to text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be converted into text by using softwares like **Microsoft OneNote** or others. You can also write programmes for creating an OCR in most of the programming languages.